# Sass: Iterate link selector via variables

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

> *[I'm using the Sass Indented syntax though feel free to answer via SCSS]*

This is the nested part of a loop in which I would like to name selectors per iteration using variables:

```
$class: 2      
@for $i from 1 through 2
  @if $i == 1
    $sel: link
  @if $i == 2
    $sel: visited
  div #s-#{$class} ul
    &:nth-child(1) li
      &:nth-child(2) a
        &:$sel
          color: $cc
```

But I'm getting:

```
"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \"&:\": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was \"$sel\"\A
```

(Yes I can see it's a syntax error)

I'm looking for an output like this:

```
div #s-2 ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) a:link {
  color: #cc0000;
}

div #s-2 ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) a:visited {
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

Is Sass capable if doing something like this? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

There's a better (more obvious) way of doing what I was trying to achieve (using $i from 1 to 1 as an example):

```
$class: 2   
@for $i from 1 through 1
  div #s-#{$class} ul
    &:nth-child(1) li
      &:nth-child(2) a
        &:visited, &:link
          color: $cc
```

Output

```
div #s-2 ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) a:visited, div #s-2 ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) a:link {
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

Though I'm till curious about methods for using selectors as variables

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#{$sel}`:

```
$class: 2
$cc: #cc0000
@for $i from 1 through 2
  $sel: ()
  @if $i == 1
    $sel: link
  @if $i == 2
    $sel: visited
  div #s-#{$class} ul
    &:nth-child(1) li
      &:nth-child(2) a
        &:#{$sel}
          color: $cc
```

which gives:

```
div #s-2 ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) a:link {
  color: #cc0000; }

div #s-2 ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) a:visited {
  color: #cc0000; }
```

Note that I had to initialise `$sel` before the ifs, probably because otherwise it stays in each if’s scope. I’ve only learned SASS yesterday, so I may well be incorrect. ;)